# Inconsistency in division of large numbers in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, division, factorial

When I calculated 24! using math library, the result is different compared to 24! calculated by dividing 25! by 25. Why is this?

```
>>> import math
>>> f=math.factorial(25)
>>> int(f/25)
620448401733239409999872
>>> math.factorial(24)
620448401733239439360000
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/` performs "true division". The result is a floating point number, which does not have enough precision to represent the exact quotient. Calling `int` cannot reverse the precision loss. The errors in floating point math & rounding are causing the discrepancy.

`//` is integer division - which is what you want:

```
>>> f = math.factorial(25)
>>> f/25
6.204484017332394e+23
>>> int(f/25)
620448401733239409999872
>>> math.factorial(24)
620448401733239439360000
>>> f//25
620448401733239439360000   # correct answer
```

Answer (score 3):

you must not use `/` operation and `int()` after division. this code will round the exact division. but when you use `factorial` for 24 python is using `*` operations.

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> f25 = factorial(25)
>>> f25
# 620448401733239439360000
```

here you can use `//` instead of `/` operation.
[see operations explanation here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp).

```
>>> f24 = factorial(24)
620448401733239439360000
>>> f25 // 25
620448401733239439360000
```